# How to run shell commands on Android phone when connected to a PC?

Tags: android, shell

I need to run `ping` request on my Android phone using the following format:

```
 ping google.com | while read pong; do echo " $pong  @$(date)"; done
```

There are some applications, such as Terminal Emulator which do that. But just in case I'm curious if I can run shell commands on phone using my PC connection, when the phone is connected to my PC?

EDIT: Yes, it works with the command. But for `> r.log` it needs root. Any suggestions for that?

Comment: Try to save log on sdcard with > /mnt/sdcard/r.log (path on your device may be different).

Comment: Yes, exactly. This worked! ... > sdcard/r.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable developer mode on the phone and use adb tool from Android SDK to do that.

I am not sure how powerful adb's shell is, but give it a try.

You can do even more with adb, check its help.

Comment: Yes, it works with the command. But for `> r.log` it needs root. Any suggestions for that?